# SIGSEGV error with QtThread on deleting QSGNode

Tags: android, c++, qt, qthread, segmentation-fault

I am working on a Qt app which runs on android & iOS.

**Scenario:**
Calling delete on a pointer causes my app to crash sometimes gives me the following error on Android.

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x3c in tid 7134 (QtThread)
```

This is caused due to a delete call in `updatePaintNode` of my `QQuickItem` derived class.

```
// My updatePaintNode logic relevant to this question
QSGNode * MyQQuickItem::updatePaintNode(QSGNode * oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData * updatePaintNodeData) {

  Q_UNUSED(oldNode)
  Q_UNUSED(updatePaintNodeData)

  if(class_mem_node != Q_NULLPTR) {
    delete class_mem_node;    // this is where the crash occurs
  }

  class_mem_node = new QSGNode;

  // Execute drawing logic

  return class_mem_node;
}
```

**Problem:**
Another window of my application is dependent on `MyQQuickItem::updatePaintNode` to execute but sometimes on Android the call to `delete class_mem_node` causes the crash with the `Fatal signal` error. Interestingly, the issue **only happens on android**, not on iOS or OSX.

**Question:**
What is wrong in my logic in `updatePaintNode` ? Is this a thread synchronisation issue?

Is there some way I can check whether the `QSGNode` is in use & return out?

Answer (score 0):

When you `return class_mem_node;` you don't have ownership of the `class_mem_node` any more.

The implementation may delete the node when it becomes not useful. It then passes `nullptr` as `oldNode` on the next call to the `updatePaintNode()`.

Don't store `class_mem_node`, use `oldNode`.